# Rate Limit an Infinite While Loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a infinite `while` loop, how can I have the loop run the next iteration every 10 minutes from the start of the loop iteration?

If the first iteration starts at 1:00am and finishes at 1:09am, the next iteration should run at 1:10am instead of waiting for another 10 minutes (like in the code snippet below). If the loop iteration took more than 10 minutes to run, the next iteration should run immediately and start the countdown of the next 10 minutes.

```
while(True):

    someLongProcess() # takes 5-15 minutes
    time.sleep(10*60)
```

**Example**

```
Loop 1: Starts 1:00am, ends 1:09am
Loop 2: Start 1:10am, ends 1:25am    # ends 5 minutes later

Loop 3: Starts 1:25am, ends 1:30am    # ends 5 minutes earlier
Loop 4: Starts 1:35am, ends 1:45am
```

Comment: What if it exceeds 10 minutes?

Comment: @thefourtheye If the loop iteration took more than 10 minutes to run, the next iteration should run immediately and start the countdown of the next 10 minutes. Added an example of the timing under different conditions

Comment: *Starts 1:10am, ends 1:09am* <- something's fishy

Comment: @hjpotter92 Oops, corrected typo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember the start time, calculate sleep time using that.

```
while True:
    start = time.time()
    some_long_process()
    end = time.time()
    remain = start + 10*60 - end
    if remain > 0:
        time.sleep(remain)
```